# "app is not supported on this device" ios 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, ios

I have given the deployment target of the app as 4.0.It s in app store.But I am having an issue downloading the app. I get the message saying that the "app is not supported on this device". I am using an iPhone 3G to try and download, using iOS 4.2.1. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: You need at least 4.3 i think. I had that problem when I was programming apps

Comment: You gave the deployment target as 4.0 in your apps build settings?

Answer (score 1):

There may be other reasons apart from the OS version. Have you specified any values for the 'Required Device Capabilities' key in your plist file? It is possible that any values there are not met by iPhone 3G (such as armv7).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons why this will happen. See my answer to [Is it possible to target older iOS versions when using Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760946/possible-to-target-older-ios-versions-when-using-xcode-4-2-and-ios-5-sdk)