# App built with Xcode 4.2 ios 5.0 crashing when installed on iphone with ios 4.3.5

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, xcode4.2

I have an app that will not build anymore on ios 4.x

Last week it worked fine, and now I can confirm 2 people with older ios' are unable to launch the app on Test Flight.

1 person (ios 4.3.x) is unable to build the app anymore in Xcode and the debugger output is as follows

```
warning: Unable to read symbols from "dyld" (prefix __dyld_) (not yet
mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols for
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3
(8F190)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit (file
not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "UIKit" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "Foundation" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols for
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3
(8F190)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
(file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreGraphics" (not yet mapped
into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "libSystem.B.dylib" (not yet
mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "libgcc_s.1.dylib" (not yet
mapped into memory).
```

I am at a loss to figure this one out.  I have been developing with the Latest SDK option and target set to 4.0.

The only change I made (that I can think of) was adding a breakpoint for all exceptions.
I am removing that and seeing if that makes a difference, but won't get feedback for a while.  I am asking here in case that is not the solution and to see if someone can ease my stress

EDIT
The breakpoint had no effect.  I didn't think it would affect running with test-flight, but I really hoped it would be the solution.  I am leaving it up here, because it is how I get the debugger to stop before main.m in Xcode 4.2 and want others to be able to set the breakpoint if they didn't know how.
[image: how I set the breakpoint]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution,

I changed focus and tried to get the app to run on my old ipod touch 3.1

I found the solution here

[Is it possible to target older iOS versions when using Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760946/possible-to-target-older-ios-versions-when-using-xcode-4-2-and-ios-5-sdk)

by mmorris

I had to do what he clearly explained and 1 more thing:
Set the compiler in the Project and Target Build Set to `LLVM GCC 4.2`
That got the app running on my old ipod touch and my the iphones with 4.x.

Not sure how any of those settings could have changed from last week, but I am not going to think about that.