# Xcode: App builds, but "runs" and "finishes" at the same time

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app created from sample code I found online. I hooked up my iPod touch 4G to my computer and everything worked fine, app ran.

Then I hooked up my iPhone 3G to the computer, established provisioning profiles, etc. In the organizer the device shows up as a green dot, so we're good. The name of the device is right there next to the run button so that's a good sign. But when I hit run it says "build succeeded" and then goes directly to "finished running  on " but nothing shows up on the app!

I've tried this with several apps now and all work on iPod touch, but none on iPhone.

Devices are running newest operating systems, 4.2 for the iPhone, Xcode version is the newest.

Comment: By third generation do you mean 3G or 3GS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a different question with more than likely the same answer
[App built with Xcode 4.2 ios 5.0 crashing when installed on iphone with ios 4.3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058177/app-built-with-xcode-4-2-ios-5-0-crashing-when-installed-on-iphone-with-ios-4-3)

I found the solution here

[Is it possible to target older iOS versions when using Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760946/possible-to-target-older-ios-versions-when-using-xcode-4-2-and-ios-5-sdk)

by mmorris

I had to do what he clearly explained and 1 more thing:
Set the compiler in the Project and Target Build Set to `LLVM GCC 4.2`
That got the app running on my older devices

Comment: +1 'The possible to target' link is the answer. A lot of answers mention architecture but don't mention the armv7 requirement in the info.plist.

Answer (score 4):

I had problem to run on simulator not on device.

Tried above options but didn't work for me.

Finally, Just Resetting Simulator did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are targeting the least iOS version and SDK that you can in the build profiles (targets, summary, Devices, Deployment target). Also, check the error console (All Output) at the bottom right and see if there's some kind of problem occurring.