# Installing XCode 4.2, 4.3 and 3.2

Tags: ios, xcode4, compatibility, xcode3.2

How can I install XCode 4.2, 4.3 and 3.2 all together? It seems like I need them all to develop for different ios versions.

I have 4.2 installed already but I need this to test my app on the new iPad, and with Xcode 4.3 and I want to test my app on the old iPod Touch 2nd generation, so I probably will need XCode 3.2 to do so...

Comment: No you don't need them all to develop for different versions...perhaps you should wait for an answer to the question you asked 30 seconds ago first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see the question from 30 seconds ago so I'll answer this one here.

Just install one version of Xcode (the latest one, 4.3) and then set the "minimum deployment version" field in the project settings to iOS 3.0 or 4.0 or 5.0 or whatever minimum iOS version you want to support (and don't do any API's newer than the version you are officially supporting... e.g. no "UIStoryboard" stuff on iOS 3 & 4, for example).

Comment: thanks, I also needed to follow this guide http://stackoverflow.com/a/7762979/31207