# Unable to load/install application on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

After following every step from how to create a certificate till adding provisional certificate to Xcode, I am unable to load the application on the iphone.

I am using Xcode 4.2 iOs 5 and trying to load application on iOS 4.1 [iPhone 3G ].

When I run other sample apps on my device, it successfully installs and runs.

My app gets buld successfully and I have configured the buld settings of my app according to my iOS.

What could be the probable reason?

Please help.

For testing purposes only, my app consists of a lone UIButton, thats it.

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving when you run the app on your device?

Comment: Are you sure the correct `Bundle Identifier` for the app is being used, thats correspondant to that of the Provisioning profile?

Comment: yes...i know you are referring to that com.companyName.somethng... and i have changed that to my provisioning profile

Comment: @bobnoble i am not rcving any message on the console... it is compiling successfully [build successfully]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the post [Is it possible to target older iOS versions when using Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760946/is-it-possible-to-target-older-ios-versions-when-using-xcode-4-2-and-ios-5-sdk) answered by mmorris.

It helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

In application build settings set deployment target lower then your device ios. Xcode templates starts with 5.0, hope this helps.

*I am using Xcode 4.2 iOs 5 and trying to load application on iOS 4.1*

Comment: did that already.... still not working.. I have done everything possible i know and mentioned on the web... but still unable to load the app...

Comment: Did you try to add new project and compile it? Still same problem for empty project?

Comment: I have already figured out the solution and i have mentioned it in the answers... i will accept in few hours once stackoverflow allows me to