# Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version but BUILD SUCCEEDED

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to deploy my app on an iPod Touch (2nd generation) which has iOS 4.2.1.
Below are the development details:

XCode Version: 4.2.1 (4D502)

iOS SDK: 5.0:   (9A334)

Deployment Target: 4.0

I installed the provision profile successfully using XCode. But, in the Devices tab in Organizer Window, it shows the following error:

Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version.

My device is listed in the top left corner of the project window. When I Run my app with my device selected, it shows 'Build Succeeded'. But the app isn't installed on my device!!!

I think there is some mismatch between Xcode version and iOS version on my device.

Please help me in this case as this is driving me nuts.
[image: Organizer view]

Comment: Is there already an older version of the app on the device? Can you make a screenshot of Organizer => Devices when the ipod is connected?

Comment: nope...this is first time I'm installing it. the screen shows green symbol next to the device name on the left pane of organizer.

Comment: hi, i have uploaded an image of the Organizer view in Xcode. Please help me out.

Comment: solution found 
very well explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760946/is-it-possible-to-target-older-ios-versions-when-using-xcode-4-2-and-ios-5-sdk]

Answer (score 1):

Don't fret. Xcode usually stores the Firmware files for your iDevice in a local folder for developer purposes(See if it is a device issue, etc). What it is saying is that the 4.2.1 Firmware is not in Xcode's folder. It is not an issue.