# How to install my PGB app on IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm developping an application for Android & IOS with phonegap/cordova & phonegap-build.

After follow this great tutorial: http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/11/phonegap/building-an-ios-signing-key-for-phonegap-in-windows , I created & installed the profile on my IPAD (IOS 5.1) but when I want to install my `.ipa` file (with Itunes) on it, I have an error because my app need a higher IOS version.

I use phonegap v3.7.0

Does anyone were able to install a phonegap app on your IOS device and is able to help me?

Comment: why do not you either donwgrade your ios target deployment or upgrade your ios to the latest version? ios 5.1 is quite old.

Comment: For the IOS target: how? I wasn't able to find the option in the config.xml
For IOS 5.1: Itunes is not able to find a newest version so I think it's the higher version for IPAD 1

Comment: Check the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760946/is-it-possible-to-target-older-ios-versions-when-using-xcode-4-2-and-ios-5-sdk

Comment: Thks you gave me the good keywords to find the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution was on the documentation...

```
<preference name="deployment-target" value="5.0" />
```

Works now, thks :)