# Trouble with .ipa installation created with phonegap-build

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, ipa

I encounter an error when I try to install my app on my ipad (IOS 5.1). This application was built with phonegap-build.

I followed these steps:

- Create & register my .mobileprovision for my UUID on apple developer portal with this tutorial: http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/11/phonegap/building-an-ios-signing-key-for-phonegap-in-windows
- Register & unlock my key on phonegap-build (I have the good UUID on logs)
- With ITUNES, I installed my .mobileprofile on my IPAD

But when I tried to install the application (.ipa) by drag & drop, the icon is shown on the Ipad but the installation stuck approximately at 75% and then, cash.

On the crashReport file I have: http://pastebin.com/4NfjCG5Y

Does someone knows a solution?

Regards,

Comment: Which version of phonegap have you used? starting phone gap 3.5.0 there is no support for iOS 5 anymore.

Comment: I use phonegap 3.7.0 .. I will try to downgrade it :)

Comment: So, why did you mark this as answered? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525492/how-to-install-my-pgb-app-on-ios

Comment: Because I was able to start the installation without any alert that tell me "This application need a higher IOS version" ...

Comment: ios 5 support was removed on cordova 3.5, so use a previous version. But use it only for testing on your iPad, you'll need at least 3.5 to submit to the apple store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my application successfully installed on an other iphone under IOS7.

So, The solution was:

- IOS 5.X is not supported anymore by phonegap >= 3.5
- phonegap 3.5 is needed to submit application to appStore

Thks!